# Check the space added to MDF by auto allocation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL server 2016 and database is set to auto grow - unlimited.

Last week we got an issue where we have ample disk space but received the below error

```
    "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.XYZ'.'index' in database 'DB_Name' because
 the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, 
dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, 
or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup."
```

Just so you know,

1. we have disk space available to grow
2. DB auto growth is set to unlimited

Then why did we get this error and how to identify this

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express?

Comment: @RossBush, Its enterprise version

Comment: I would also set your log files to unlimited growth, if not already set.

Comment: @RossBush, logs are unlimited as well

Comment: @scree - Did you double check that the files are actually being placed on the drive think they are?

Comment: Yes @RossBush, I have checked it for sure and a small correction, its standard edition. Also when I check the disk IO logs, I could see a spike in disk latency at the time when this incident happened

Comment: Express has a maximum of 10GB per database

Comment: Do you have growth set to a percentage instead of a fixed size? If the file size is large something like a 10% growth can be massive.